# Moving View Controller to the top of navigation stack iOS

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

How do I move a VC pushed into navigation stack to be on top?

Suppose I pushed it in this order

```
Push VC1 
Push VC 2
Push VC 3
```

So now currently I have VC3 on top. 
How do I programmatically bring VC2 to front? So that the stack becomes

```
VC1,VC3,VC2
```

Comment: Did you try getting viewControllerArray and changing order of Array and then set [navigationController setViewController:newViewControllerArray]? I guess it should work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a developer, you have an access to navigation controller stack by manage its viewControllers array:

```
NSArray *currentStack = self.navigationController.viewControllers
```

[image]

> Discussion The root view controller is at index 0 in the array, the
>   back view controller is at index n-2, and the top controller is at
>   index n-1, where n is the number of items in the array.
>
> Assigning a new array of view controllers to this property is
>   equivalent to calling the setViewControllers:animated: method with the
>   animated parameter set to false.

It is simple an array, that holds the vcs that are currently in nav's stack
and you can manage this array like the others:

```
NSMutableArray *tempArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: currentStack];

[tempArray removeObjectAtIndex:1];
[tempArray addObject:secondVC];

self.navigationController.viewControllers = tempArray;
```

There are a set of available methods that you can play with:

[image]

Hope it helps)

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, you don't.

You would need to use `popToViewController:animated:` to pop to VC1. Then your view controller stack would be

```
  VC1
  root view controller
```

(You said you pushed VC1. A navigation controller has a root view controller which is always at the bottom of the stack.)

### Edit:

As @AlexKosyakov pointed out, it **is** possible to edit a navigation controller's navigation stack by manipulating the array. (Cudos and an up vote to him for pointing that out.)

However, I would say that you should **NOT** do that. A navigation stack is an Apple-provided user interface model that provides a consistent user experience, and creates an expectation on the part of the user. If I see the visual cues of a navigation stack (push animation, back buttons, etc) then I have the expectation, conscious or unconscious, that pressing the back button will take me back to the previous screen, and that the order of screens in the stack will not change out from under me.

Answer (score 1):

First, let me state that that is a very unusual thing to need to do. Normally, you would just pop VC 3 off the stack to go back.

That said, you can get the array of view controllers from vc3.navigationController.viewControllers, rearrange the items in the array and set the viewControllers property back on the navigation controller.